# How to make label increase in increments as user adds Calories in my App

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, addition

I have a food diary in my app and i'm wondering how I can write the logic so my label can update to the accumulation of calories the user has eaten for the day. I'm thinking maybe I can save the state of the cals as an integer of other variable... but other than that i'm pretty stuck. Heres a pic of the app:

[image: Calories]

This is all I have so far in my function... I'm thinking of adding a class level variable such as

var appJustLoaded = true
to save the state of the app, then switching it off once the user inputs a food. Any suggestions? I basically want my calories label to update as the user inputs more food with calories. I know its quite simple but im stuck haha

```
 func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String, section: Int) {

    var newCals = Int(calories)


    calsforToday.text = calories
```

Comment: Temporarily you can store it in a member variable in the ViewController, but you need to look into something like CoreData to store it more permanently.

Comment: Are you wanting the label to have a running total of the calories? You can have a variable called `totalCalories` and in your `didAddRow` function you can add the calories to the total. Then since this is simply and integer you can save it using UserDefaults. Check this out for an example of how to use  UserDefaults to store data. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults

Comment: @naturaln0va works, please put it as an answer so i can +1 you. thank you!

Comment: Sure thing. Glad It was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a variable called `totalCalories` and in your `didAddRow` function you can add the calories to the total. Then since this is simply and integer you can save it using UserDefaults. Check this out for an example of how to use UserDefaults to store data.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults

Answer (score 0):

You could append the new calories to an array and then you can total them.

```
var caloriesArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String, section: Int) {

    var newCals = Int(calories)

    caloriesArray.append(newCals!)

    calsforToday.text = caloriesArray.reduce(0, +)

}
```

If you are storing the data in CoreData the you would use something like this when you are fetching the data to get your total.

```
let result = try! context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject];
let sum = result.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.value(forKey: "Value") as? Int16 ?? 0) }
```